# How do I improve the performance of an read-write intensive imagemagick script?

Tags: bash, image-processing, imagemagick

I use a bash script to process a bunch of images for a timelapse movie. The method is called shutter drag, and i am creating a moving average for all images. The following script works fine:

```
#! /bin/bash
totnum=10000
seqnum=40
skip=1
num=$(((totnum-seqnum)/1))
i=1
j=1
while [ $i -le $num ]; do
    echo $i
    i1=$i
    i2=$((i+1))
    i3=$((i+2))
    i4=$((i+3))
    i5=$((i+4))
    ...
    i37=$((i+36))
    i38=$((i+37))
    i39=$((i+38))
    i40=$((i+39))
    convert $i1.jpg $i2.jpg $i3.jpg $i4.jpg $i5.jpg ... \
            $i37.jpg $i38.jpg $i39.jpg $i40.jpg \
            -evaluate-sequence mean ~/timelapse/Images/Shutterdrag/$j.jpg 
    i=$((i+$skip))
    j=$((j+1))
done
```

However,  i noticed that this script takes a very long time to process a lot of images with a large average window (1s per image). I guess, this is caused by a lot of reading and writing in the background.

Is it possible to increase the speed of this script? For example by storing the images in the memory, and with every iteration deleting the first, and loading the last image only.

I discovered the `mpr:{label}` function of imagemagick, but i guess this is not the right approach, as the memory is cleared after the `convert` command?

Comment: As you appear to read each image many times, you should consider making a RAMdisk (what OS do you use?) and converting all your JPEGs to `MPC` format files on the RAMdisk up front to minimise the decoding load - maybe use GNU Parallel for that too.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10 is the OS that i am using. Is there an easy way to set up and use the RAMdisk?

Comment: Here's an example http://www.hecticgeek.com/2015/12/create-ram-disk-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Recompiling ImageMagick with OpenMP support will help improve the `-evaluate-sequence` performance (if not already enabled).

Comment: I will take a look into the RAMdisk tomorrow. Compiling is unfortunately not an option for me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Suggestion 1 - RAMdisk**

If you want to put all your files on a RAMdisk before you start, it should help the I/O speed enormously.

So, to make a 1GB RAMdisk, use:

```
sudo mkdir /RAMdisk
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1024m tmpfs /RAMdisk
```

**Suggestion 2 - Use MPC format**

So, assuming you have done the previous step, convert all your JPEGs to MPC format files on the RAMdisk. The MPC file can be dma'ed straight into memory without your CPU needing to do costly JPEG decoding as MPC is just the same format as **ImageMagick** uses in memory, but on-disk.

I would do that with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel -X mogrify -path /RAMdisk -fmt MPC ::: *.jpg
```

The `-X` passes as many files as possible to `mogrify` without creating loads of `convert` processes. The `-path` says where the output files must go. The `-fmt MPC` makes `mogrify` convert the input files to `MPC` format (Magick Pixel Cache) files which your subsequent `convert` commands in the loop can read by pure DMA rather than expensive JPEG decoding.

If you don't have, or don't like, **GNU Parallel**, just omit the leading `parallel -X` and the `:::`.

**Suggestion 3 - Use GNU Parallel**

You could also run @chepner's code in parallel...

```
for ...; do
   echo convert ...
done | parallel
```

Essentially, I am echoing all the commands instead of running them and the list of echoed commands is then run by **GNU Parallel**. This could be especially useful if you cannot compile **ImageMagick** with OpenMP as Eric suggested.

You can play around with switches such as `--eta` after `parallel` to see how long it will take to finish, or `--progress`. Also, experiment with `-j 2` or `-j4` depending how *big* your machine is.

---

I did some benchmarks, just for fun. First, I made 250 JPEG images of random noise at 640x480, and ran chepner's code *"as-is"* - that took 2 minutes 27 seconds.

---

Then, I used the same set of images, but changed the loop to this:

```
for ((i=1, j=1; i <= num; i+=skip, j+=1)); do
   echo convert "${files[@]:i:seqnum}" -evaluate-sequence mean ~/timelapse/Images/Shutterdrag/$j.jpg
done | parallel
```

The time went down to 35 seconds.

---

Then I put the loop back how it was, and changed all the input files to MPC instead of JPEG, the time went down to 36 seconds.

---

Finally, I used MPC format **and** GNU Parallel as above and the time dropped to 19 seconds.

I didn't use a RAMdisk as I am on a different OS from you (and have extremely fast NVME disks), but that should help you enormously too. You could write your output files to RAMdisk too, and also in MPC format.

Good luck and let us know how you get on please!

Comment: Hey, I finally had the time to look into the topic. I used your suggestions and it improved the processing a lot. I choose the RAMdisk to be 4GB, however, that only fits around 150 images of 2MP resolution. Therefore, i am using a loop that loads a bunch of images, processes these and removes them from the RAMdisk afterwards. Previously 1,11s/img (SSD), now 0,42s/img (MPC on RAM) (40 img windows). Mogrify uses `-format MPC`. Thank you a lot for your time and help!

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad it worked out for you. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing you can do in `bash` to speed this up; everything except the actual IO that `convert` has to do is pretty trivial. However, you can simplify the script greatly:

```
#! /bin/bash
totnum=10000
seqnum=40
skip=1
num=$(((totnum-seqnum)/1))


# Could use files=(*.jpg), but they probably won't be sorted correctly
for ((i=1; i<=totnum; i++)); do
  files+=($i.jpg)
done

for ((i=1, j=1; i <= num; i+=skip, j+=1)); do
  convert "${files[@]:i:seqnum}" -evaluate-sequence mean ~/timelapse/Images/Shutterdrag/$j.jpg
done
```

Storing the files in a RAM disk would certainly help, but that's beyond the scope of this site. (Of course, if you have enough RAM, the OS should probably be keeping a file in disk cache after it is read the first time so that subsequent reads are much faster without having to preload a RAM disk.)

Comment: Thanks, this look way better!