# Shell/C semaphore

Tags: c, bash, unix, semaphore

I have a C program and a bash script that need exclusive access to a file. I've seen that [you can use mkdir with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10197327/15173), but does this mix well with C? Is it safe to just test the presence of a directory, create and then delete it?

What I'm actually doing: a C program keeps rewriting a file with new data that is then read from a bash script.

Comment: What's your problem? I'm not sure what you're really asking here.

Comment: Write to a differently named file in C and when you are finished writing it, rename it such that it overwrites the existing file. If the `bash` script happens to be reading the file as you overwrite it, it will still be able to finish reading the file if it has it open. Then next time the `bash` script opens the file, it will get the newly renamed one.

Comment: While I have accepted @Dmitry answer as it addresses my question, I'm going with your suggestion as it effectively solves my problem in a simpler way and without semaphores to begin with.

Comment: The suggestion is indeed nice, but keep in mind that if your C code runs quickly enough to create two new files or more while the shell script reads one, the script will miss some of the files.

Comment: If the writing is frequent, the idea of the file being on a small RAMdisk comes to mind - to save thrashing your disk... http://stackoverflow.com/a/39924756/2836621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of semaphores is atomicity, and if you check for directory presence using your own code, you will lose that property. What you should do it use `mkdir` function and check for `EEXIST` error code once it returns:

```
char * lockdir="/tmp/myscript.lock";
int retval=mkdir(lockdir, S_IRWXU);
if(retval == 0) printf("successfully acquired lock: %s", lockdir);
else if(errno == EEXIST) printf("cannot acquire lock %s", lockdir);
else printf("Something bad happened (permissions/no free space/read-only filesystem)")
```